# Confused on Derby Client Server

Tags: java, database, database-connection, derby, javadb

With reference to [*Libraries provided by Derby*](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/getstart/rgslib46043.html), I am confused about connecting my Java application, which needs a connection to a server database (Derby/Java DB on NetBeans). In particular, I am confused between

> Network Server library

and

> Network client library

Could any one please define them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about. The server needs to have derbynet.jar in its classpath; your client application needs to have derbyclient.jar in its classpath. Beyond that, what sort of definition are you looking for?

Comment: That you mean i should have derbyclient.jar in my netbeans/Project/Lib folder. @BryanPendleton

Comment: I'm not sure how NetBeans classpath definitions work. You can put derbyclient.jar in any of a variety of locations, so long as it is part of your application classpath when you run your application.